# code does not work in Dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have some code which I tested and it works in my environment, I changed agent.add(value) with console.log(value), and the result is printed. However, when I try it in dialogflow fulfillment, it does not run the response and the body is always undefined.

Does anyone has any idea what can make the code not run in Dialogflow Fulfillment. Thanks.

```
 function SearchKnowwledgeBaseMethod(intention){
    var username = "something";
    var password = "something";
    var auth = "Basic " + Buffer.from(username + ":" + password).toString('base64');
    var result;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      rq(
        {
          url : `https://xxxxxx/api/now/table/kb_knowledge?sysparm_query=textCONTAINS${intention}`,
          headers : {
            "Authorization" : auth
          }
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            if (typeof body !== undefined) {
              const obj = JSON.parse(body);
              if (obj.result.length > 0){
                result = obj.result[0].text;
              }
            }
          }else {
            reject("I have a problem");
          }
          resolve(result);
        });
    });
  }

  function SearchKnowledgeBase(agent){
    var intention = agent.parameters.intention;
        return SearchKnowwledgeBaseMethod(intention).then(function(result){
            if (result !== undefined){
                console.log(result);
                return agent.add(result);
            } else {
                var stringArray = intention.split(' ');
                stringArray.forEach(function (item) {
                    return SearchKnowwledgeBaseMethod(item).then(function(answer){
                        console.log(answer);
                        return console.log(answer);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('search_knowledge_base', SearchKnowledgeBase);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the question, which is very simple. The reason is that I am using the free version of Firebase so it does not allow calling external API, when I switch to Pay as you go plan then the API request works fine. 
credit to this video on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4IPOeFCDxI&t=591s

Answer (score 0):

There are two things, that need to be taken care of.

```
if (result !== undefined){
                console.log(result);
                agent.add(result); // no need to return here you are already returning a promise just do agent.add(result)
            } else {
                var stringArray = intention.split(' ');
                // I don't think you can return promises in loop for dialogflow, just return one promise 
                stringArray.forEach(function (item) {
                    return SearchKnowwledgeBaseMethod(item).then(function(answer){
                        console.log(answer);
                        return console.log(answer);
                    });
                });
            }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, I already modified it but still it does not work. the thing is I already tested it in my local laptop, and it works at least, however in the fulfillment, the request result is always undefined. I think fulfillment firebase has some firewall that block my request.